# strange character ? added at the end of URL

Tags: web, url, joomla, url-rewriting

I have a very very strange thing only on some websites.
I have restarted the server where many websites are hosted (for maintenance reasons) and after reboot, some websites only have a **?** at the end of their URL.
At the end of website URL I get **index.php?** instead of index.php only previously.

Normally URL is https://www.example.com/index.php , but now suddenly is https://www.example.com/**index.php?**

For info, before restart everything was fine.
Nothing has been changed (on nginx or admin tools file maker..nothing)

Do you have an idea why?
Do you think admin tools nginx file maker can be the root cause?

I don't understand why and how, as everything was ok before server reboot.

Thanks
L.

Comment: I guess it's not an real issue a '?' character just separate the url from the GET parameters. I guess a ?(which don't have a parameter after it) at the end and a url without ? is equivalent.

Comment: The problem, for me, is this question: why this character was not displayed before server reboot, and displayed After ?

Comment: Nobody has an Idea? I think problem is coming from nginx but I cannot fins where :-/

Comment: If you think it is an nginx issue you might want to tag it that way or post on serverfault stack exchange.

Comment: I'm not totally sure the problem is coming from nginx but ok why not. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause : wrong nginx configuration.